# How does the contract TwitterHumanityApplicant queries the Twitter API?

Tags: contract-development

[TwitterHumanityApplicant](https://etherscan.io/address/0x9d661f7773be14439b4223f5b516bc7ef67b0369#contracts) is (as I understand) a smart contract that validates that a human (or a Twitter user) owns a wallet.

I was expecting to see in the contract code something that resembles a call to the Twitter API to find a tweet by the user that includes the wallet address. I couldn't find anything that looks like an API endpoint. Maybe I missed it, as I am very new to Solidity.

**How does this contract checks that the Twitter account owner tweeted the wallet address?**

Answer (score 2):

As per Lauri's answer, it doesn't immediately appear there are any oracle calls in any of the contracts used. (I had a poke around.)

Looking at [this](https://medium.com/marbleorg/introducing-humanity-90ddf9ead235) Medium post, it appears that verification currently relies on real humans:

> "Unfortunately, authenticating a human identity is not a problem that
>   a smart contract can solve. Instead, it is up to the community to come
>   to a consensus on the best approach for identity verification.
>
> As a first approach, we recommend social verification."

Answer (score 1):

Without trying to interpret everything the contract does, it's obvious that there is nothing concrete about verifying Twitter handle. It has multiple calls to other external contracts which may do the verification part but impossible to know.

In general smart contracts can't interact with the rest of the world. They are fully isolated inside the EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine) and are deterministic. All information they have must be already inside the blockchain and therefore they can't directly query external sources.

What is needed is something called *oracles*. They provide data from the internet into the blockchain on demand. So you can call an oracle smart contract, it emits certain events, the oracle's backend systems notice the events and issue a transaction to the blockchain where they include the requested data. In that way the requested data is added into the blockchain and made available for any smart contract which requested the data.

So if the contract you showed us really does some Twitter verification it has to utilize oracles somewhere. As there are no direct oracle calls in the displayed code the call must be somewhere in the external contracts.